# Get the matched column value of the global table from the temp table's field input

Tags: sql-server

I have created the temp table and stored the id of the customer.

Now I want to get the Name of the customer from the id of the temp table while inserting it into another table.

```
Insert INTO Cust1 Values(Id, Name)
Values SELECT ID From @Temp (here from the specific id i want to insert the name.)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to accomplish here.  Can you show us, by way of sample data, what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

If am not wrong you just need simple `INSERT from SELECT`. Filter the `ID` in `Where` clause

```
Insert INTO Cust1 Values(Id, Name)
SELECT ID,Name From @Temp Where ID = --your id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `insert . . . select`.  Presumably, you need to look up the name in some other table:

```
insert into Cust1 (Id, Name)
    select t.ID, o.name
    from @Temp t join
         othertablehere o
         on t.id = o.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert INTO Cust1 Values(Id, Name)
Values SELECT ID, cust.name From @Temp temp,  customers cust where top.itop.IDtop.itop.ID=cust.Id